# Replace string from character onwards

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've got a string like so

```
Jamie(123)
```

And I'm trying to just show `Jamie` without the brackets etc

All the names are different lengths so I was wondering if there was a simple way of replacing everything from the first bracket onwards?

Some others are displayed like this

```
Tom(Test(123))
Jack   ((4u72))
```

I've got a simple replace of the bracket at the moment like this

```
mystring.Replace("(", "").Replace(")","")
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB.NET

```
mystring.Substring(0, mystring.IndexOf("("C)).Trim()
```

C#

```
mystring.Substring(0, mystring.IndexOf('(')).Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

One logic; get the index of the `(` and you can trim the later part from that position.

```
public static string Remove(string value)
            {
                int pos = value.IndexOf("(");
                if (pos >= 0)
                {
                    return value.Remove(pos, remove.Length);
                }
                return value;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

[`String.Remove(Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc.aspx) will do what you need:

```
Deletes all the characters from this string beginning at a 
specified position and continuing through the last position.
```

You will also have to [`.Trim()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) as well given the data with padding:

```
mystring = mystring.Remove(mystring.IndexOf("("C))).Trim()
```

Comment: MSDN says Remove takes an int, no? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc.aspx

Comment: trim() - Removes all leading and trailing white-space characters from the current String object. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx

Comment: Yes, .Remove returns a string object, then it gets trimmed and assinged.

Answer (score 0):

aneal's will work.  The alternative I generally use because it's a bit more flexible is .substring.

```
string newstring = oldstring.substring(0,oldstring.indexof("("));
```

If you aren't sure that oldstring will have a "(" you will have to do the test first just as aneal shows in their answer.